# splice is not working in my case

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Not sure where my mistake is, I expect ["name"] became ["-name"]

```
let sortedKey = ['name']
key = "name"

let i = sortedKey.indexOf(key)
sortedKey.splice(i, `-name`)

console.log(sortedKey)
```

but it didn't?

Comment: There is documentation on [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you could read... Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) need a 3 parameters  `array.splice(start, deleteCount, item)`

For Better replace with direct array index `sortedKey[i]= '-name'`

```js
let sortedKey = ['name']
key = "name"

let i = sortedKey.indexOf(key)
sortedKey[i]= '-name'

console.log(sortedKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the 3 parameter version of [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
let sortedKey = ['name']
key = "name"

let i = sortedKey.indexOf(key)
sortedKey.splice(i, 1, `-name`)

console.log(sortedKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass 2nd parameter as number of items to remove [check here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

> **SYNTAX**
>
> **array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)**

```js
let sortedKey = ['name']
key = "name"

let i = sortedKey.indexOf(key)
sortedKey.splice(i, 1, `-name`)

console.log(sortedKey)
```